# Javascript event: getElementByID does not find inserted element

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

Mystery: I can't seem to pass an id to an inserted element and then remove that element using the id. I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null"

So the `getElementById(thisCorrection)` is not finding the element defined by `addButton.id=thisCorrection`. Weird!

What I am trying to do: click on a button, which will insert a 2nd button (b2), make an id for b2 by incrementing a counter, mouseover b2 button will remove the button. Do it all in Javascript, not jQuery.

(I thought this was simple!)

```js
  
   correctionID=0

   function removeButton(thisCorrection){
           document.getElementById(thisCorrection).remove()
   }

   function checkInput() {
      correctionID += 1;
      thisCorrection="correction" + correctionID.toString();
      var addButton=document.createElement("button");
      addButton.id=thisCorrection;
      addButton.innerHTML="here is the new button";
      addButton.addEventListener ("mouseenter", 
                      removeButton(thisCorrection), false);
      this.parentElement.appendChild(addButton) ;}
```

```html
<div> <button onclick="checkInput()"><span style='background:yellow'>click to add button </span></button> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer... (after much blood, sweat, tears and Googling!)

Why wasn't it working before? The argument to the function is an event, not a button!

```js
  
   correctionID=0

   function removeButton(evt) {
         addButton=evt.target; //cannot says evt.remove() !
         console.log(evt.target.id);
         addButton.remove();  
         
   }

   function checkInput(btn1) {
      correctionID += 1;
      thisCorrection="correction" + correctionID.toString();
      var addButton=document.createElement("button");
      btn1.parentElement.appendChild(addButton) ;
      addButton.id=thisCorrection;
      addButton.innerHTML="Here is the new button";
      addButton.addEventListener("click",removeButton, false);
       };
```

```html
<div> <button onclick="checkInput(this)"><span style='background:yellow'>click to add button </span></button> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler form that shows incredible javascript/dom weirdness (for a novice). Looks like I am going to have to use Jquery...

```js
  
   correctionID=0

   function removeButton(addButton){
         //addButton.remove();  
         // Wow! Uncomment the line above and no new button appears.
         // that's because clicking on button 1 runs 
         // removeButton even though the event is 
         // attached to the new button not to button 1!
         console.log(addButton.id);
   }

   function checkInput(btn1) {
      correctionID += 1;
      thisCorrection="correction" + correctionID.toString();
      var addButton=document.createElement("button");
      btn1.parentElement.appendChild(addButton) ;
      addButton.id=thisCorrection;
      addButton.innerHTML="Here is the new button";
      addButton.addEventListener ("dblclick",removeButton(addButton), false);
       };
```

```html
<div> <button onclick="checkInput(this)"><span style='background:yellow'>click to add button </span></button> </div>
```